# Mocking NamedTemporaryFile write & close file

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

How can i mock NamedTemporaryFile with write and close in this examples :

```
def submit_form(self,pdf_bytes,file_path):
      with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+b') as temp:            
            temp.write(pdf_bytes)
            
            with open(temp.name, 'rb') as pdf:
                file_path = self._google_cloud_storage.upload_file(file_path,pdf,"application/pdf")
                pdf.close()
            temp.close()
```

**Here is my test**

```
@patch.object(tempfile,"NamedTemporaryFile",return_value = None)
@patch('builtins.open', new_callable=mock_open())
    def test_submit_form(self):
        self._payment_approval_service.submit_form(Mock(),"testfilepath.pdf")
```

**Test result**:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Mock'
    in submit_form
        temp.write(pdf_bytes)
    _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
    
    args = (<Mock id='140604437181680'>,), kwargs = {}
    
        @_functools.wraps(func)
        def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    >       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    E       TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Mock'
```

this means the NamedTemporaryFile().write function is not mocked right ?

Answer (score 0):

You run

```
self._payment_approval_service.submit_form(Mock(),"testfilepath.pdf")
```

where Mock() is the `pdf_bytes` parameter, so doing

```
temp.write(pdf_bytes)
```

will naturally cause the error you get

```
 bytes-like object is required, not 'Mock'
```

so you should pass something like `b"test data"` instead

not sure how to actually mocks `self`

in any case, you don't need call `close()` because you are already using `with` which does that automatically

Comment: how about the write function? how we make sure that the write function is mocked?